# SSH into GCE VM via web browser with restricted IP addresses

Tags: google-compute-engine

I've setup my VM to use a network only allowing a whitelist of IP addresses on the SSH protocol on port 22.

If I try to SSH into my instance via the web browser within the developer console the connection is correctly refused, as it isn't originating from one of my permitted IP addresses.

I'm curious if there is a way to have my whitelist of IP addresses and still SSH into the VM via the browser. I know I can still connect using gcutil, and it would obviously work if I had the IP address.

Looking at the documentation, it isn't listed as a [known issue](https://developers.google.com/compute/docs/ssh-in-browser#known_issues).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When connecting from Developer Console SSH tool the instance receives connection from Google IP range, I made a test and it was from 74.125.0.0/16 range. You could try to temporary white list this range and see if you can access.

Regards
Paolo

Comment: Thanks for your help, Paolo. I do have an external static IP address which is in my white-list. So I can SSH into my instance via gcutil or another ssh client on my machine, but not within the web browser on the same machine (and same network connection). I thought the ssh request was originating from a Google server with a different IP address when you connect in the browser, which is why I think it is being refused. This is only an assumption though -- I'm not very experienced with GCE so I might not be understanding something...

Comment: Yes when connecting from Developer Console SSH tool the instance receives connection from Google IP range, I made a test and it was from 74.125.0.0/16 range. You could try to temporary white list this range and see if you can access.

Comment: Adding that range did work. I just checked the output of the instance and saw the SSH connection coming from an IP address in that range. I think I will only add it when I wish to ssh via the browser. I'm not sure of the security implications. It's much nicer viewing log files in a window I can resize more easily. Thanks for your help.

Comment: In my test the range was more restricted (74.125.47.0/24) but maybe it changes in time...